# Connector for Microsoft Dynamics: Some synchronized Invoices have Total Amount=0 in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

When synchronizing invoices from AX to CRM with [Connector for Microsoft Dynamics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dynamicsconnector/), many invoices are synchronized correctly. At the same time some invoices in CRM have the Total Amount set to 0. It appears that this issue occurs for invoices with only a single invoice product.

Re-running the synchronization appears to set the Total Amount correctly on some, but not all invoices.

The total amount on the invoices is set correctly in AX. What should I do to make all invoices in CRM have the correct Total Amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Settings->Administration->System Settings->Sales` you can set `Use System Pricing Calculation` to No. This will make CRM use the values provided from the Connector.